# C++ string assigning values to at(int) function

Tags: c++, string

```
string test = "Word";
test.at(0) = 'J';
cout << test << endl;
```

I'm a java guy who is now learning c++ and this behavior of the at() function is bothering me.  What exactly is at() returning so that I can change the value in the string.  Is it a pointer?

Comment: Look at a reference (no pun intended).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::at` returns a reference to the specified character of the string.

If `text` is an instance of `std::string`, then `text.at(pos)` returns a reference to the character at position `pos`. You can assign a new value to it and it will modify the original string.